# How to change an image with another image in the same HTML using user interaction with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing an exercise on doing a TIC TAC TOE in spanish game,  my question is, in the new version of the game, I need to make it available for the user to choose their desire icon image to use in the tic tac toe game.

I have the game developed the first version of the game with no change of icons.

My question is, how to I change the default images of "X" and "O", using different options that the user can see in the same HTML file, and when they select the image or click on a button "set image player 1" or "set image player 2", the default images of "X" and "O" change to what user chose.

I know I need to use a variable to change the "X" and "O" when users touch on the button/image they desire to change as their icon.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    table {
      border: 5px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 5px solid black;
      padding: 2px;
    }
    
    #bttn {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
    }
    
    #result,
    #puntaje {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
      font-size: 80px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <title>
    Practico 2
  </title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="title">TA-TE-TI</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="img1" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="img2" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="img3" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="img4" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="img5" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="img6" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="img7" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="img8" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="img9" src="https://rb.gy/ewvlsc" alt="?" width="100px" height="100px">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="bttn" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Posicion</button>
  <br>
  <p id="result">

  </p>
  <p id="puntaje">

  </p>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    function block() {
      let c1 = document.querySelector("#img1").addEventListener("click", blink1);
      let c2 = document.querySelector("#img2").addEventListener("click", blink2);
      let c3 = document.querySelector("#img3").addEventListener("click", blink3);
      let c4 = document.querySelector("#img4").addEventListener("click", blink4);
      let c5 = document.querySelector("#img5").addEventListener("click", blink5);
      let c6 = document.querySelector("#img6").addEventListener("click", blink6);
      let c7 = document.querySelector("#img7").addEventListener("click", blink7);
      let c8 = document.querySelector("#img8").addEventListener("click", blink8);
      let c9 = document.querySelector("#img9").addEventListener("click", blink9);
      let bttn = document.querySelector("#bttn").addEventListener("click", guardar);
    }

    block();

    // Symbols
    let x = "https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/x-simbolo_318-1407.jpg";
    let o = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR-nKrx88anoryiFTXJCzkz-QldJxop3wOhOQ&usqp=CAU";
    let ask = "https://rb.gy/ewvlsc";

    // Images
    let i1 = document.querySelector("#img1");
    let i2 = document.querySelector("#img2");
    let i3 = document.querySelector("#img3");
    let i4 = document.querySelector("#img4");
    let i5 = document.querySelector("#img5");
    let i6 = document.querySelector("#img6");
    let i7 = document.querySelector("#img7");
    let i8 = document.querySelector("#img8");
    let i9 = document.querySelector("#img9");

    // jugadas para X
    let l1hx = 0; // linea 1 horizontal
    let l2hx = 0; // linea 2 horizontal
    let l3hx = 0; // linea 3 horizontal
    let l1vx = 0; // linea 1 vertical
    let l2vx = 0; // linea 2 vertical
    let l3vx = 0; // linea 3 vertical
    let l1dx = 0; // linea 1 diagonal
    let l2dx = 0; // linea 2 diagonal

    // jugadas para O
    let l1ho = 0; // linea 1 horizontal
    let l2ho = 0; // linea 2 horizontal
    let l3ho = 0; // linea 3 horizontal
    let l1vo = 0; // linea 1 vertical
    let l2vo = 0; // linea 2 vertical
    let l3vo = 0; // linea 3 vertical
    let l1do = 0; // linea 1 diagonal
    let l2do = 0; // linea 2 diagonal


    // jugadores
    let jugadorX = 0;
    let jugadorO = 0;


    // SE TERMINO EL JUEGO
    /*
    document.querySelector("#img1").removeEventListener("click", blink1);
    document.querySelector("#img2").removeEventListener("click", blink2);
    document.querySelector("#img3").removeEventListener("click", blink3);
    document.querySelector("#img4").removeEventListener("click", blink4);
    document.querySelector("#img5").removeEventListener("click", blink5);
    document.querySelector("#img6").removeEventListener("click", blink6);
    document.querySelector("#img7").removeEventListener("click", blink7);
    document.querySelector("#img8").removeEventListener("click", blink8);
    document.querySelector("#img9").removeEventListener("click", blink9);
    */

    // result
    let rslt = document.querySelector("#result");

    // puntaje
    let pnt = document.querySelector("#puntaje");

    function guardar() {

      if (i1.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img1").removeEventListener("click", blink1);
      }

      if (i2.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img2").removeEventListener("click", blink2);
      }
      if (i3.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img3").removeEventListener("click", blink3);
      }

      if (i4.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img4").removeEventListener("click", blink4);
      }

      if (i5.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img5").removeEventListener("click", blink5);
      }
      if (i6.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img6").removeEventListener("click", blink6);
      }

      if (i7.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img7").removeEventListener("click", blink7);
      }

      if (i8.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img8").removeEventListener("click", blink8);

      }

      if (i9.src != ask) {
        document.querySelector("#img9").removeEventListener("click", blink9);
      }

      if (i2.src === x && i5.src === x && i8.src === x) {
        l2vx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }
      if (i2.src === o && i5.src === o && i8.src === o) {
        l2vo = 2;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }

      if (i1.src === x && i2.src === x && i3.src === x) {
        l1hx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }
      if (i1.src === o && i2.src === o && i3.src === o) {
        l1ho = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }

      if (i1.src === x && i4.src === x && i7.src === x) {
        l1vx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }
      if (i1.src === o && i4.src === o && i7.src === o) {
        l1vo = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }

      if (i3.src === x && i6.src === x && i9.src === x) {
        l3vx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }
      if (i3.src === o && i6.src === o && i9.src === o) {
        l3vo = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }

      if (i7.src === x && i8.src === x && i9.src === x) {
        l3hx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }
      if (i7.src === o && i8.src === o && i9.src === o) {
        l3ho = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }

      if (i4.src === x && i5.src === x && i6.src === x) {
        l2hx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }
      if (i4.src === o && i5.src === o && i6.src === o) {
        l2ho = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
      }

      if (i1.src === x && i5.src === x && i9.src === x) {
        l1dx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
        rslt.innerHTML = "<br/>SE TERMINO EL JUEGO.";
        document.querySelector("#img1").removeEventListener("click", blink1);
        document.querySelector("#img2").removeEventListener("click", blink2);
        document.querySelector("#img3").removeEventListener("click", blink3);
        document.querySelector("#img4").removeEventListener("click", blink4);
        document.querySelector("#img5").removeEventListener("click", blink5);
        document.querySelector("#img6").removeEventListener("click", blink6);
        document.querySelector("#img7").removeEventListener("click", blink7);
        document.querySelector("#img8").removeEventListener("click", blink8);
        document.querySelector("#img9").removeEventListener("click", blink9);
        return false;
      }
      if (i1.src === o && i5.src === o && i9.src === o) {
        l1do = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
        rslt.innerHTML = "<br/>SE TERMINO EL JUEGO.";
        document.querySelector("#img1").removeEventListener("click", blink1);
        document.querySelector("#img2").removeEventListener("click", blink2);
        document.querySelector("#img3").removeEventListener("click", blink3);
        document.querySelector("#img4").removeEventListener("click", blink4);
        document.querySelector("#img5").removeEventListener("click", blink5);
        document.querySelector("#img6").removeEventListener("click", blink6);
        document.querySelector("#img7").removeEventListener("click", blink7);
        document.querySelector("#img8").removeEventListener("click", blink8);
        document.querySelector("#img9").removeEventListener("click", blink9);
        return false;
      }

      if (i3.src === x && i5.src === x && i7.src === x) {
        l2dx = 1;
        jugadorX = l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx + l1dx + l2dx;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
        rslt.innerHTML = "<br/>SE TERMINO EL JUEGO.";
        document.querySelector("#img1").removeEventListener("click", blink1);
        document.querySelector("#img2").removeEventListener("click", blink2);
        document.querySelector("#img3").removeEventListener("click", blink3);
        document.querySelector("#img4").removeEventListener("click", blink4);
        document.querySelector("#img5").removeEventListener("click", blink5);
        document.querySelector("#img6").removeEventListener("click", blink6);
        document.querySelector("#img7").removeEventListener("click", blink7);
        document.querySelector("#img8").removeEventListener("click", blink8);
        document.querySelector("#img9").removeEventListener("click", blink9);
        return false;
      }
      if (i3.src === o && i5.src === o && i7.src === o) {
        l2do = 2;
        jugadorO = l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo + l1do + l2do;
        pnt.innerHTML = "Jugador X tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorX;
        pnt.innerHTML += "<br/>Jugador O tiene un puntaje de " + jugadorO / 2;
        rslt.innerHTML = "<br/>SE TERMINO EL JUEGO.";
        document.querySelector("#img1").removeEventListener("click", blink1);
        document.querySelector("#img2").removeEventListener("click", blink2);
        document.querySelector("#img3").removeEventListener("click", blink3);
        document.querySelector("#img4").removeEventListener("click", blink4);
        document.querySelector("#img5").removeEventListener("click", blink5);
        document.querySelector("#img6").removeEventListener("click", blink6);
        document.querySelector("#img7").removeEventListener("click", blink7);
        document.querySelector("#img8").removeEventListener("click", blink8);
        document.querySelector("#img9").removeEventListener("click", blink9);
        return false;
      }

      if (l1dx === 0 || l1do === 0 || l1ho + l2ho + l3ho + l1vo + l2vo + l3vo <= l1hx + l2hx + l3hx + l1vx + l2vx + l3vx) {
        rslt.innerHTML = "Elije una jugada.";
      }

    }

    function blink1() {

      if (i1.src === x) {
        i1.src = o;
      } else {
        i1.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink2() {

      if (i2.src === x) {
        i2.src = o;
      } else {
        i2.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink3() {

      if (i3.src === x) {
        i3.src = o;
      } else {
        i3.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink4() {

      if (i4.src === x) {
        i4.src = o;
      } else {
        i4.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink5() {

      if (i5.src === x) {
        i5.src = o;
      } else {
        i5.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink6() {

      if (i6.src === x) {
        i6.src = o;
      } else {
        i6.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink7() {
      let i7 = document.querySelector("#img7");

      if (i7.src === x) {
        i7.src = o;
      } else {
        i7.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink8() {

      if (i8.src === x) {
        i8.src = o;
      } else {
        i8.src = x;
      }
    }

    function blink9() {

      if (i9.src === x) {
        i9.src = o;
      } else {
        i9.src = x;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need a server. HTML can't store any data.

Comment: why don't you just store the image url of the chosen o or x symbol in browser's ```window.localStorage``` ?

Comment: Do u need an online img file to read as symbols

Comment: I changed it to using the same html file and hiding the div when the user hasn't chosen an image yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did finish this exercise, and what I did was use

```
if (document.querySelector(#image).src === "defaultImage.jpg") { document.querySelector(#image).src = "player1.jpg" } else { document.querySelector(#image).src = "player2.jpg" }
```

Where player1 and player2 were the chosen images from each player in the previous part of the js, inside the same page, with a button that shows the game once both players chose an image.

The default ? symbol of he TIC TAC TOE changes into image of player 1 or image of player 2.

If you have comments you can comment below.

Answer (score 2):

As @Simplicius said in most cases for what you're asking for you need a server. I think you may be looking at the problem in the wrong way. What is your ultimate goal? Is it a 2 player game that multiple people can interact with? If so doing it with a single page is not possible without something hacky like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Somehow I dont think that's what your teacher has in mind though. I would revisit the problem and really understand what's being asked of you before moving forward.

Comment: What the exercise asks is to put a few images in the same html file as options and when the user clicks on the desire image or a button below the image, the default "x" or "o" becomes the image chosen.

With an option for player 1 and player 2.

Change the images source to the new image.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like two players are at the same computer and take turns, one being x and the other one o until the game is finished. If that's the case I think you're on the right track with your original post. You'll want some sort of toggle between xPlayer and oPlayer's turn, then add event listeners to each div. When a player clicks on a square not already clicked update the innerHTML with the corresponding image for that player, then check to see if it's 3 in a row which would be another function.

Comment: Yes, that is what i'm trying to do, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store image inside browser memory as base64 and use it for displaying inside html dom as follow:

*somewhere in html*

```html
<input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file">
```

*in js*

```js
  const input = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
  const reader = new FileReader;
  let storedImage;
  reader.onload = () => {
    const dataURL = reader.result;
    const base64 = reader.result.split(",").pop();
    storedImage = base64;
  }
  input.onchange = () => {
    reader.abort();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
```

*when rendering image:*

```js
const img = document.createElement(`img`)
img.src = `data:image/png;base64, ${storedImage}`
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/client-side-upload-image-preview?file=index.html)

Although that would only work for single browser and for syncing between players on different browsers you would need server side solution